# Add date and time to pdf output file name

Tags: pdf, r

I am exporting graph outputs from R to a pdf file.

I would like to add the `Sys.time()` and `Sys.Date(`) to the outfile name.

For instance I have a statement

```
pdf("output filename.pdf", 8,10)
```

I would like to output to look like
output `filename 2010-03-25 2pm.pdf`

or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
pdf (file=paste (Sys.time(), ".pdf", sep=""))
plot (rnorm (100))
dev.off()
```

Comment: I found pdf title a nice touch to my pdf generation.

Answer (score 19):

Combine `Sys.time()` with some formatting to get what you want:

```
paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %I-%p"), "pdf", sep = ".")
[1] "2011-03-24 03-PM.pdf"
```

Formatting options can be found in `?strptime`

Answer (score 7):

Break it into two steps for easy implementation on other docs.

```
st=format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")
paste("filename_",st, ".pdf", sep = "")
[1] "filename_2018-06-19_11:20.pdf"
```

Comment: Great idea! I had problem to use colon in a file name and therefore simply removed it. Instead I use st=format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M").