# Inserting date & time into WMF filename

Tags: r, graph, output

Creating some graphs, and want the date/time of creation to be in the filename.  I found the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424648/add-date-and-time-to-pdf-output-file-name) very helpful on that topic, and

```
 paste("plotname",Sys.time(),".wmf",sep='')
```

does in fact spit out

```
[1] "plotname2013-07-02 11:55:04.wmf"
```

but

```
win.metafile(paste("plotname",Sys.time(),".wmf",sep=''))
# win.metafile("test.wmf")
ggplot(data.file, aes(x = group, y = delta)) + geom_boxplot()
dev.off()
```

gives

```
Error in win.metafile(paste("plotname", Sys.time(), ".wmf", sep = "")) : unable to start win.metafile:plotname2013-07-02 11:56:23.wmf() device
```

where it works with the simpler win.metafile("test.wmf") command.  What's the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried reformatting `Sys.time` with `format` like they did in the second answer to the question you referenced? For example: `format(Sys.time(),"%y%m%d")`

Comment: That works, thanks.  Any idea why?

Comment: Refer to Hong Ooi's answer with characters not allowed in Windows file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 win.metafile(paste("plotname",format(Sys.time(),"%y%m%d.%M%H"),".wmf",sep=''))
```

Works for me. I think the problem was with the format of the file - as per Hong Ooi's answer Windos does not allow colons in file names. This gives the time as the year/month/day.hour/minute

Check out http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html for more information on formatting. You can add different things too, like:

```
format(Sys.time(),"%y see? %m")
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows file names can't contain the following characters:

```
< > : " \ / | ? *
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the reference, or a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) on the topic.